# Why IDA debugger keep receiving SIGTRAP or SIGSEGV after set a break-point and then deactivated that break-point

Tags: ida, android, linux

Here's the problem:

- I set a breakpoint in IDA debugger
- the program stop at the breakpoint
- deactivated the breakpoint
- IDA keep receiving SIGTRAP or SIGSEGV

---

( program stop at breakpoint as expected ) :

[image]

( deactivated the breakpoint and continue execution ) :

[image]

[image]

[image]

( and the SIGTRAP or SIGSEGV goes on and on till program stop, and the adb shell shows)  :

```
Error: Oops! internal error 30060 occurred.
```